ValueError: You can't pass `load_in_4bit`or `load_in_8bit` as a kwarg when passing `quantization_config` argument at the same time
I'm currently fine-tuning the Mistral 7B model and encountered the following error:
ValueError: You cannot simultaneously pass the load_in_4bit or load_in_8bit arguments while also passing the quantization_config argument.
You can access the notebook where this error occurred via the following link:
Notebook Link
# Load base model(Mistral 7B)
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(  
    load_in_4bit= True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type= "nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype= torch.bfloat16,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant= False,
)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        base_model,
        load_in_4bit=True,
        quantization_config=bnb_config,
        torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
        device_map="auto",
        trust_remote_code=True,
)
model.config.use_cache = False # silence the warnings. Please re-enable for inference!
model.config.pretraining_tp = 1
model.gradient_checkpointing_enable()

# Load tokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(base_model, trust_remote_code=True)
tokenizer.padding_side = 'right'
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
tokenizer.add_eos_token = True
tokenizer.add_bos_token, tokenizer.add_eos_token


You can set load_in_4bit to True in your BitsAndBytesConfig
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
)

You do not need to pass this to your AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        model_name,
        # load_in_4bit=True, This is not needed
        quantization_config=bnb_config,
        torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
        device_map="auto",
        trust_remote_code=True,
    )


It seems like argument load_in_4bit or load_in_8bit confilts with argument quantization_config
you can try to delet load_in_4bit=True in from_pretrained
2974         # handling bnb config from kwargs, remove after `load_in_{4/8}bit` deprecation.                                                        
2975         if load_in_4bit or load_in_8bit:
2976             if quantization_config is not None:
2977                 raise ValueError(
2978                     "You can't pass `load_in_4bit`or `load_in_8bit` as a kwarg when passing "
2979                     "`quantization_config` argument at the same time."
2980                 )
2981 
2982             # preparing BitsAndBytesConfig from kwargs
2983             config_dict = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in inspect.signature(BitsAndBytesConfig).parameters}
2984             config_dict = {**config_dict, "load_in_4bit": load_in_4bit, "load_in_8bit": load_in_8bit}
2985             quantization_config, kwargs = BitsAndBytesConfig.from_dict(
2986                 config_dict=config_dict, return_unused_kwargs=True, **kwargs
2987             )
2988             logger.warning(
2989                 "The `load_in_4bit` and `load_in_8bit` arguments are deprecated and will be removed in the future versions. "
2990                 "Please, pass a `BitsAndBytesConfig` object in `quantization_config` argument instead."
2991             )

As shown above, you should pass your load_in_4bit in BitsAndBytesConfig
